# Remove subdirectories from a list of directories in a GNU Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile variable (declared before any recipe) which contains a list of directories:

```
DIRS = foo bar bar/baz ../qux/quux ../qux
```

Now I want to remove the subdirectories which are already contained by other directories:

```
foo bar ../qux
```

I don't care about keeping the order or the relativity of paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a combination of GNU-Make's [file name functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) (which can be used on any arbitrary strings) and [text functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html). The concept is simple:

1. Build a list of patterns that are the original directory list plus an amount of path beyond what was included. The `%` is going to be the wild card here, so  we're going to append `/%` to each word in the list using `$(addsuffix <suffix>,<word list>)`.
2. Remove anything that matches that list of patters from the original word list. This is what  `$(filter-out <pattern>,<word list>)` does.

Put it all together and it might look like this:

```
DIRS = foo bar bar/baz ../qux/quux ../qux
PARENTS = $(filter-out $(addsuffix /%,$(DIRS)),$(DIRS))

default:
    @echo $(PARENTS)
```

Running that Makefile should output:

```
foo bar ../qux
```

Comment: This is clever, thanks ! It doesn't handle the case `foo bar ..` (get `foo bar ..` instead of `..`) but using the `realpath` command did the trick.